# How to get all phone numbers based on only the accound sid and token with Twilio?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

It appears going through the Twilio github that there is no way to retrieve a list of registered phone numbers based on the account info alone, that you must have the sid for every single phone number hardcoded in your application or database.

I would like to have several end user Twilio accounts which only have one number, and retrieve that through the Twilio client without having to store the sid, since I might as well just store the number itself.

Is this a faulty way of thinking about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the phone numbers for an account or sub-account "*based on only the account sid and token*".

***Code:***

---

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "ACc0966dd96e4d55d26ae72df4d6dc3494";
        const string authToken = "your_auth_token";


        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var incomingPhoneNumbers = IncomingPhoneNumberResource.Read();

        foreach(var record in incomingPhoneNumbers)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(record.PhoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

---

***Docs:***

---

Get started with .NET in 10 minutes
(https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows)

and

The Twilio C#/.NET SDK
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp)

and

List all IncomingPhoneNumber of your Account
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incoming-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-list-all-incomingphonenumber-of-your-account&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=5.x)